# paypal error code 10413

Tags: php, express-checkout

i am implementing express checkout, i want to set shipping amount here is NVP string i am using

```
$nvpstr="&L_NAME0=".$L_NAME0."&L_NAME1=".$L_NAME1."&L_NAME2=".$L_NAME2."&L_AMT0=".$L_AMT0."&L_AMT1=".$L_AMT1."&L_AMT2=".$L_AMT2."&L_QTY0=".$L_QTY0."&L_QTY1=".$L_QTY1."&L_QTY2=".$L_QTY2."&MAXAMT=".(string)$maxamt."&AMT=".(string)$amt."&ITEMAMT=".(string)$itemamt."&ReturnUrl=".$returnURL."&CANCELURL=".$cancelURL ."&CURRENCYCODE=".$currencyCodeType."&PAYMENTACTION=".$paymentType."&SHIPPINGAMT=".$L_SHIPPING_CHARG;
```

But its giving error code 10413 that " The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts." what is the exact paramerter in which i can pass Shipping Amt & TAX

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by mismatched amount for the order. Especially:

AMT:Total of order, including shipping, handling, tax, and any other billing adjustments such as a credit due. 
ITEMAMT :Sum of costs of all items in this order.

See more:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECCustomizing/